# Simson line in the regular 17-gon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, polygons

In geometry, given a triangle $ABC$ and a point $P$ on its circumcircle, the three closest points to $P$ on lines $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$ are collinear. The line through these points is the [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line) of $P$, named for Robert Simson.

[image]

Let $A_1A_2\ldots A_{17}$ be a [regular 17-gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) as in the following figure:

[image]

> **Question**: How can one prove that the Simson line of $A_9$ with respect to the triangle $A_1A_8A_{14}$ is perpendicular to the side $A_{15}A_{16}$?

Comment: Please provide links to the used notions (Simson line, possibly relevant properties related to the question) and most important the own tries to solve the issue. (What kind of solution is expected?! Analytic, syntetic, or even a computer assisted solution would be ok?!)

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect that they are perpendicular, other than the picture? Because there are a lot of possible angles near $\pi/2$ that don't equal $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a synthetic solution.
First of all a picture. The given $17$-gon has in my notation the vertices $0,1,2,\dots,16$. (Because a computer aided solution would have them labeled as $\zeta^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots, 16$, where $k$ is the primitive $17$.th root of unity, $\zeta =\exp\frac{2\pi i}{17}$.)

**The construction first:**

> We build the Simson line of $\boxed 8$ w.r.t $\Delta 0,7,13$.
>
> For this, we have to construct the perpendiculars from $\boxed 8$ to the sides of the triangle. These perpendiculars pass further through points of the $34$-gon having $0,1,2,\dots,16$ also as vertices. We denote the vertex of this $34$-gon between the points $k$ and $(k+1)$ by $kA$, where $A$ is only a suffix. Then:
>
> - The perpendicular from $\boxed 8$ on $7,13$ passes through $3A$.
> - The perpendicular from $\boxed 8$ on $13,0$ passes through $13A$.
> - The perpendicular from $\boxed 8$ on $0,7$ passes through $7A$.
> - The Simson line is then the line through $(8,3A)\cap(7,13)$, and $(8,13A)\cap(0,13)$, and $(8,7A)\cap(0,7)$. (These three points are colinear.)
>
> [image: 3279408, 17-gon, Simson line of a vertex]

---

Try here to find the solution without reading the following...

---

**The solution:**

Let $P,Q$ be the projections of $8$ on the sides $7,13$ and $7,0$ of the given triangle:

[image: 3249708, solution]

Then we have
$$
\widehat{7,P,Q} =
\widehat{7,8,Q} =
\widehat{7,8,7A} =
\widehat{7,13,7A} \ .
$$
(We have used $7,P,8,Q$ concyclic, sice the angles in $P,Q$ are right, and the fact that $8,Q$ passes through $7A$, and the equality of the two angles against the arc $7,7A$.)

In particular, $(P,Q)\|(13,7A)$.

It remains to observe that $(13,7A)\perp(14,15)$, since the angle between them is half of the difference of the measures of the arcs
- from $15$ to $7A$, and
- from $13$ to $14$, 
and we get
$$
\frac 12\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac 1{17}\left(9\frac 12-1\right)=\frac \pi 2\ .
$$

$\square$

---

**Note:**

From the figure we observe the coincidence that the diametral line $5,13A$ also passes through the point of intersection of the Simson line and $(14,15)$. How can we prove and use this fact? (Consider $(12,13)\cap(14,15)$, and search for the mirror points...)

Answer (score 1):

This result generalizes nicely, and leads to a very neat follow-on result.

---

Abusing notation to define $\operatorname{cis}\theta := (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, we can coordinatize with $A_m := \operatorname{cis}2\theta_m$.

- The Simson line of $\triangle A_i A_j A_k$ for $A_p$ has direction vector $$\operatorname{cis}(\theta_i+\theta_j+\theta_k-\theta_p) \tag{1}$$
- The line $\overleftrightarrow{A_qA_r}$ (with $\theta_q\neq \theta_r$) has direction vector 
  $$\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta_q+\theta_r)\right) \tag{2}$$
- These vectors ---and therefore the corresponding lines--- are perpendicular if and only if
  $$\sin(\theta_i+\theta_j+\theta_k-\theta_p-\theta_q-\theta_r) = 0 \tag{3}$$ That is,

  > $$\theta_i+\theta_j+\theta_k = \theta_p+\theta_q+\theta_r \pmod{\pi} \tag{$\star$}$$

---

For the points $A_m$ on a regular $n$-gon, we can take $\theta_m = \pi m/n$ (recall that we incorporated a $2$ into the definition of $A_m$, so we don't use $2\pi$ here). In this case, $(\star)$ becomes
$$i+j+k = p + q + r \pmod n \tag{4}$$

For the problem at hand, we have $n=17$, $i=1$, $j=8$, $k=14$, $p=9$, $q=15$, $r=16$. And, indeed,
$$i+j+k = 23 = 40 = p+q+r \pmod{17}$$ 
This verifies the claim. $\square$

---

But there's more to say ...

Given that $p$, $q$, $r$ are interchangeable in $(\star)$, we have a situation where the Simson line of $\triangle A_i A_j A_k$ with respect to *any* of $A_p$, $A_q$, $A_r$ is perpendicular to the line through the other two. But, the sets $\{i,j,k\}$ and $\{p,q,r\}$ are *also* interchangeable: the Simson line of $\triangle A_p A_q A_r$ with respect to *any* of $A_i$, $A_j$, $A_k$ is perpendicular to the line through the other two.

> We could say, then, that $\triangle A_i A_j A_k$ and $\triangle A_p A_q A_r$ are "ortho-Simsonian conjugates".

(Actually, "ortho-Simsonian" seems to suggest that there's some orthogonality among Simson lines, so a better term is needed.)

Here's a diagram of OP's scenario, with $\triangle A_1 A_8 A_{14}$ and $\triangle A_9 A_{15} A_{16}$.

[image]

We see that, as a bonus, *all six Simson lines are concurrent*! The point of concurrency is

> $$\frac12\left(A_i+A_j+A_k+A_p+A_q+A_r\right) \tag{$\star\star$}$$