# On concurrent Simson lines

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Let X, Y , Z be the midpoints of the major arcs BC, CA, AB of the circumcircle of triangle ABC. Prove that the Simson lines of X, Y , Z with respect to ABC are concurrent.

As mentioned in the comments, I created this problem myself by playing around in software such as GeoGebra. I want to find out why this property seems to hold.

Here's a diagram: [image: ddd]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you,  without wasting anyone's time explaining what you already understand or using techniques above your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements without commentary of your own tends to give the wrong impression.) Edit the question to add details.

Comment: Which arc BC,the one containing A or the other one?

Comment: @JJM: (I don't think that "@above" and "@3above" stuff works; besides, it's harder for a particular person to know who ou're addressing that way. Just "@" the specific user names.) You should mention in the body of the question that you devised the problem, and you should give some idea of why you believe the result is plausible. If you have a solution and are looking for something "better", you should include that solution so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort. (Also, note that Math.SE isn't the place to "challenge" users with problems whose solutions you already know.)

Comment: i actually dont know the solution, i was just playing around in geogebra and found this result. sorry about the @above things.

Comment: @JJM: That's good to know, and I appreciate the edit. Since you've been using GeoGebra, perhaps you can provide a screenshot to help show plausibility. (It would probably also help to at least link to [a definition of Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).) But you could still add context: What level of proof are you comfortable reading? Do you want straight synthetic geometry? Is trig okay? Coordinates? Vectors? Complex numbers?

Comment: @Blue anything is fine. by the way i am also trying to find my own solution. im pretty sure this may be able to solved by taking a clever perspective. thank you for being patient with my lack of insight of the generally accepted rules of Math.SE.

Comment: @JJM The common point is the incenter of medial triangle.

Comment: @timon92 was that concluded by observation or do you have a justification?

Comment: @JJM I can prove this by an angle chasing. Try to do it yourself, it is not hard.

Comment: @timon92 ok, so i would like to prove that the incenter I of DEF (medial triangle) lies on each of the simson lines? how would i proceed?

Comment: @JJM Start by noting that the Simson lines pass through midpoints of sides of $ABC$. Then prove that the Simson lines are parallel to corresponding angle bisectors of $ABC$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109350/discussion-between-jjm-and-timon92).

Comment: With a tedious coordinate proof, I can show that for distinct points $A:=(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$, $B:=(...\beta...)$, $C:=(...\gamma...)$, $D:=(...\delta...)$, $E:=(...\epsilon...)$, $F:=(...\phi...)$, the Simson lines to $\triangle ABC$ with respect to $D$, $E$, $F$ (and vice-versa!) concur iff $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma = \delta+\epsilon+\phi \pmod{2\pi}$$ and, in such a case, the point of concurrency is $\tfrac12(A+B+C+D+E+F)$. Hmmm ... Reminds me of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3344356/409) about Simson lines of triangles in an $n$-gon.

Comment: @Blue there was also another question on concurrency of Simson lines here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631219/